# before i was married

Tags: tense, past-perfect

*I mean, back before I was married I had this one girlfriend who was fat.*

Source: Chuck Palahniuk – Romance (published in Playboy, August 2011)

I tend to apply the rules of the usage of past perfect to this sentence. Would it be possible using this tense? – "…before I was married I had had this one girlfriend who had been fat"?

Answer (score 1):

If you say "girlfriend who *had been* fat" (instead of "was") it would mean that she had gotten thinner before she became his girlfriend.

**When we were kids we used to explore a derelict building which had been a tire factory.**

Comment: what about : "who she was fat"?

Comment: @Cardinal "who she was fat" is a bad construction in the first place. Please, if you have more questions, ask them as a new question.

Comment: @Catija sorry it was typo, I meant who was fat

Comment: "Who was fat" is the construction from the original sentence. Yes, it's fine.